# Meteor Getting Users CreatedAt and Emails

Tags: javascript, meteor

My app has autopublish turned on.

I want to create a page that shows the lists of the registered users, their emails and when they are created. So I build of the grid from the Meteor.users collection.

I parsed the information like this

```
{{#each users}}
<ol>
   <li>
      {{username}}
   </li>
   <li> 
      {{emails[0].address}}
   </li>
   <li> 
      {{createdAt}}
   </li>
 </ol>
{{/each}}
```

However I managed to only get the username. The emails return `[Object object]` in the grid and the createdAt returns empty.

How can I correctly parse these two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you'll need to publish the user's data yourself. autopublish does do this but it restricts the fields.

Publish the data to yourself with the below, you can use the `fields` option to explicitly define which fields you would like the client to see. With autopublish these fields are usually just username and profile.

Server side

```
Meteor.publish("users", function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{createdAt: true, profile: true, emails: true, username: true}});
});
```

Client side

```
Meteor.subscribe("users");
```

Then you should be able to see `.createdAt` and the emails too.

For your email you would need to use `{{emails.[0].address}}` as `[]` doesn't work in Spacebars/Handlebars like it would in javascript

Comment: Can you please change 'users' to 'userData'? Also, i tried `{{emails.0.address}}` but the server console says error `=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client\views\user\user.html:76: Expected IDENTIFIER
...            {{emails.0.address}}         ...
                        ^

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
`

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha Sorry about that i made a mistake in my answer i've updated it now

Comment: Akshat, thanks so much! Your answer finally got me what I needed. :)